# как в LuaBridge передать указатель на объект из одной функции в другую?

Tags: c++, api, lua

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в LuaBridge  передать указатель на объект из одной функции в другую?

```
using namespace luabridge;
struct a {
    int x;
    a(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
        cout << "call constructor with parameters\n" <<  endl;
    }
    void get() const /* время жизни lua.*/ {cout << x << endl;  }
    ~a() { cout <<"desctor\n"  << endl; }
};
a* create(){
    a b(56);
    return &b;
}
void pri(a *b, lua_State* L) {
    b->get();  
}        

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    getGlobalNamespace(L).addFunction("create", create)
    .addFunction("pri", pri);

    luaL_dofile(L, "main.lua");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);    }
```

Comment: `a b(56); return &b;` - ой-ой